# Gesture recognizer selector is not triggered when translating initWithCoder: implementation to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have the following piece of code in Objective-C that i need to convert to Dwift.

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    }
    return self;
}
```

I tried the following approach, but the selector is not getting triggered:

```
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let x:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
    }
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Objective-C code calls `addGestureRecognizer`. Your Swift code does not.

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    let x:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
    addGestureRecognizer(x)
}
```

Comment: Yea i noticed that after i typed the question. Will accept it anyways. Thanks